# Is there a way to achieve something similar to Google Maps Distance Matrix API using React Native Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-native, google-distancematrix-api, react-native-maps

Is there a way to achieve something similar to [Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/) using [React Native Maps](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps)?

I need to calculate the distance between 2 markers (or chain 3+ different markers). The Google Maps Distance Matrix API is able to calculate the distance within the path of the road. So its more accurate than just a straight line between two markers.

Is there any way to achieve this using React Native Maps? If this is possible using React Native alone and using the Google Maps API or any other API then that would also be great.

Comment: The DirectionsService will calculate the distance/duration for a single route as well (and handles waypoints, where the DistanceMatrix doesn't).